# Releasing a parameter

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, protocols

let's say if you have class doing something on some other thread. And has delegate of its own.

```
@protocol XRequestDelegate;

@interface XRequest : NSObject {
    id<XRequestDelegate> delegate;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) id<XRequestDelegate> delegate;

- (void) doSomething;
@end


@protocol XRequestDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)request:(XRequest *)request didFinish:(id)object;
- (void)request:(XRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError*)error;

@end
```

doSomething eventually calls either `request:didFinish:` or `request:didFailWithError:`

and lets use this class in our object;

```
- (void)doRequest
{
    XRequest *request = [[XRequest alloc] init];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request doSomething];
}

- (void)request:(XRequest *)request didFinish:(id)object
{
    // Use object whatever you want
    [request release];
}

- (void)request:(XRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    //Log Error
    [request release];
}
```

we have an instance of `XRequest` allocated and eventually released in methods.

Can we say this is a wrong way of memory management. Should we expand the scope of `XRequest` object?

Comment: In that case I'd make doSomething a class method (+). Otherwise you need to instantiate an object which does nothing but instantiate another one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple's [fundamental rule of memory management](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH) states:

> You only release or autorelease objects you own.

I think in this case, you would **not** be breaking that rule, since your delegate is the object that allocated the request. You do mention multiple threads, however, and the best practice there is to have one object per thread (don't allocate the request on one thread and release it on another).

Comment: As you see, allocation and releasing the object are on the same thread. I meant in `doSomething` method there will be some more threaded process.

Comment: Also i am releasing my own objects at the same memory address. Allocated and referenced objects are same. There will be no alternative situation. Also i dont have any chance to release my object more than i allocated (or retain)

Comment: @Alkimake I can't see that your delegate methods are being called on the same thread, because you don't show the code of `doSomething`, but if that is the case, then I think you're fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen apple examples do it that way (I believe it is one of the media player ones) but I would say that is a wrong way of doing memory management. What happens if the class referencing `XRequest` gets deallocated before `XRequest` finishes? How do you prevent any further delegate calls or release it.

What you want to do is retain the request in an ivar and then remove its delegate and release it and set it to nil on the finish/fail methods and in `-(void)dealloc`.